# Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии кнопки сработали две функции?

Tags: python, tkinter, button

Я ввожу информацию в `данные1` и `данные2`. Потом при нажатие кнопки пуск значения которые я ввёл в `данные1` и `данные2` присваиваются через функцию переменной `as1` и `as2`. (Правильно ли я сделал функцию хз :-), если что поправьте) Но как сделать что-бы при нажатие кнопки пуск сработали сразу две функции? Кнопка должна быть одна.

```py
from tkinter import *


def save_file():
    hteniezapis = w2.get(0.0, END)


def save_file2():
    hteniezapis1 = w3.get(0.0, END)


w1 = Tk()

w1.title("Тест")
w1.geometry("440x350")
w1.resizable(width=False, height=False)

puch = Button(text="ПУСК", background="#369DA0", foreground="#fff", font="20", width=12, command=save_file)
puch.place(relx=.5, rely=.8, anchor="c", height=50, width=110, bordermode=OUTSIDE)

w2 = Text(width=52, height=2, bg="#F8F8FF", fg='black', font='Arial 11', wrap=WORD)
w2.place(x=10, y=36)
l2 = Label(text="Данные1", font="20").place(x=180, y=6)

w3 = Text(width=52, height=2, bg="#F8F8FF", fg='black', font='Arial 11', wrap=WORD)
w3.place(x=10, y=116)
l3 = Label(text="Данные2", font="20").place(x=180, y=86)

as1 = save_file()
as2 = save_file2()

w1.mainloop()
```

Comment: Функции save_file и save_file2 сделал неправильно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Но как сделать что-бы при нажатие кнопки пуск сработали сразу две
>   функции?

Чтобы при клике на `puch` запустились `save_file` и `save_file2` нужно вызвать их в функции (например, в лямбде):

```
puch = Button(
    text="ПУСК", background="#369DA0", foreground="#fff", font="20", width=12, 
    command=lambda: save_file() or save_file2()
)
```

У подхода с `or` в `lambda` есть некоторые минусы, например, то что вызываемые функции должны возвращать то, что по условию их результат должен быть `False`, поэтому можно сделать так:

```
    command=lambda: (save_file(), save_file2())
```

---

Или сделать отдельную функцию и в ней вызывать подфункции:

```
def func_puch():
    save_file()
    save_file2()

puch = Button(
    text="ПУСК", background="#369DA0", foreground="#fff", font="20", width=12, 
    command=func_puch
)
```

---

**UPD.**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


def on_puch():
    # as1 и as2
    hteniezapis = w2.get(0.0, END)
    hteniezapis1 = w3.get(0.0, END)

    messagebox.showinfo("Info", "hteniezapis={}\nhteniezapis1={}".format(hteniezapis, hteniezapis1))


w1 = Tk()

w1.title("Тест")
w1.geometry("440x350")
w1.resizable(width=False, height=False)

puch = Button(text="ПУСК", background="#369DA0", foreground="#fff", font="20", width=12, command=on_puch)
puch.place(relx=.5, rely=.8, anchor="c", height=50, width=110, bordermode=OUTSIDE)

w2 = Text(width=52, height=2, bg="#F8F8FF", fg='black', font='Arial 11', wrap=WORD)
w2.place(x=10, y=36)
l2 = Label(text="Данные1", font="20").place(x=180, y=6)

w3 = Text(width=52, height=2, bg="#F8F8FF", fg='black', font='Arial 11', wrap=WORD)
w3.place(x=10, y=116)
l3 = Label(text="Данные2", font="20").place(x=180, y=86)


w1.mainloop()
```

Comment: А не будет ли лучше написать `;` вместо `or`? Как я понимаю, в данном случае без разницы, а вот если бы `save_file()` вернула `True`, то `save_file2()` не выполнилась.

Comment: @Anton, если вместо `or` поставить `;` то получите `invalid syntax` :)

Comment: Да, действительно, я неправ. Меня смутила возможность написать `command=lambda: save_file(); save_file2()`, а то, что это на самом деле выполнение только `save_file`, я понял только сейчас

Comment: @Anton, придумал способ проще `or`: `lambda: (save_file(), save_file2())`

Comment: Каким образом я могу проверить через print передаётся ли as1 и as2 то что я ввожу в данные1 и данные2?Где в коде поставить print,а то разобраться не могу)

Comment: По коду в `as1 = save_file()` `as2 = save_file2()` переменные `as1` и `as2` значения будут как `None`, т.к. если функция явно не вызывает `return`, то вернется `return None`. Можете подробнее объяснить что хотите сделать?

Comment: Я пишу графический интерфейс для программы.Изначально в as1 и в as2 я ввожу свои данные,а дальше программа работает с ними.Так вот мне надо сделать так что-бы я вводил эти данные в окне графического интерфейса.Сейчас без графического интерфеса это выглядит так as1 = и какие-то цифры и буквы (у as2 так же),она их берёт и работает с ними.

Comment: @Leon, добавил пример получения и использования данных